# What prevents a Jquery oncontext from firing?

Tags: jquery

[image]I have a large table based web app running. Most cells in each column are editing by including a oncontextmenu= function like this;

```
<td oncontextmenu=\"MapLat('$row[latitude]');return false;\" class=\" editLAT \" id=\"Lat:$row[recordID]\"> $row[latitude] </td>
```

It occurred to me it might be cleaner to use Jquery like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "td.editLAT" ).contextmenu(function() {
        alert( "Handler for LAT called." );
}); });
```

However it never fires the function. Below is a link to a jsfiddle that demonstrates the functionality. The jsfiddle works! But the same exact code in my app does not. Nothing happens, no error is shown in the log or the inspector. It just doesn't fire.
Yes, I'm including the same version of Jquery as the jsfiddle, everything is the same. The tables are all built via PHP/MySQL but look exactly like that in the example.

jsfiddle at.    https://jsfiddle.net/kkaiser/sumnncrm/31/

What could be causing this function not to fire in my production page but works in all test pages including the jsfiddle?

Comment: Hard to say for certain without seeing the code in question. Is the selector correct? Is the selector running AFTER the tables have been rendered in the DOM?

Comment: I copied the code out of my program and added it to the jsfiddle. So its correct syntactically including the selector.

Comment: td .editLAT is not the same as td.editLAT. The first means "things with the class editLAT inside of things with the tag td". The second means "things with the tag td that also have the class editLAT.

Comment: Thanks @CHBuckingham for your input and for catching this in the example code. The space is not in the jsfiddle code so the example worked. I added it the td as you suggested and it still works...in the jsfiddle. But it still does not work in my program. I have edited my example above, the jsfiddle to show your suggestion and added a screenshot of the right click result.